# Show UITableView accessory based on time of date

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So I have a UITableView, and I want to put a check next to a row depending on the time of day.  For example, if its 9:00 AM, I want a check on the first row only, etc.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
cell.accessoryType = [self setTheAccessaryType:indexPath.row];
```

Here is that method:

```
-(UITableViewCellAccessoryType )setTheAccessaryType:(int)indexPath {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];


    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    int hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
    int minute = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

    [dateFormatter release];


    if (indexPath == 0 && hour >= 8 && minute >= 20) {
        NSLog(@"in here");
        return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: What’s the problem? What’s happening instead of what you want?

Comment: Most of the time I get no check mark.  With a few changes, I once get everything checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning AccessoryNone in both cases, maybe you wanted to return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark from inside your if statement.